# Refreshing a ListView to reflect ArrayList population

Tags: java, android, sqlite, exception, arraylist

I am running into an issue where my app crashes and I am given an error that reads

```
04-28 15:08:32.378: E/AndroidRuntime(27229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 15:08:32.378: E/AndroidRuntime(27229): Process: com.example.datetracker, PID: 27229
04-28 15:08:32.378: E/AndroidRuntime(27229): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
04-28 15:08:32.378: E/AndroidRuntime(27229):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

I can successfully remove an item from the lstEvents arraylist and I can also remove the event object from the database, but I can't seem to have it disappear from the screen. No matter what I do it seems to keep refreshing the listview with the same contents.

**What am I doing wrong? I keep getting this IndexOutOfBoundsException, and I am pretty sure it is because the view is not updating properly and it continues to allow me to swipe-to-dismiss which is in return trying to delete objects which eventually are not going to be there.**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
ArrayList<Event> templstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

Context context;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    // ///////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    context = this;

    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
            listView,
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {

                EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(context, lstEvents);
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

                @Override
                public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(ListView listView,
                        int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        if (lstEvents.isEmpty()){
                         Log.e("EMPTYLIST","THELISTISEMPTY");
                        }
                        else
                                                        db.deleteEvent(lstEvents.get(position));
                            lstEvents.remove(position);
                            //adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));

                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during
    // ListView scrolling,
    // we don't look for swipes.
    listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    lstEvents = db.getAllContacts();
    adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// @Override
// protected void onResume() {
// // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// super.onResume();
// //
// /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
// DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
// //
// /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// lstEvents = db.getAllContacts();
// EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);
// adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
// adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
// }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            Bitmap bitmap = b.getParcelable("BITMAP");

            // ///CONVERTING A BITMAP TO A BYTE[]
            byte[] image = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            image = bos.toByteArray();
            // ///////

            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
            /**
             * CRUD OPERATIONS
             */

            Log.e("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addEvent(new Event((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 101),
                    title, time, date, image));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");

            lstEvents = db.getAllContacts();

            adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // logging all events

            for (Event ev : lstEvents) {
                String log = "Id: " + ev.get_Id() + " ,Title: "
                        + ev.get_title() + " ,Date: " + ev.get_date()
                        + " ,RESOURCEID: " + ev.get_image();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Name: ", log);

            }

            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

    }
}
}
```

**SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener**

```
public class SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
// Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
private int mSlop;
private int mMinFlingVelocity;
private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
private long mAnimationTime;

// Fixed properties
private ListView mListView;
private DismissCallbacks mCallbacks;
private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

// Transient properties
private List<PendingDismissData> mPendingDismisses = new ArrayList<PendingDismissData>();
private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
private float mDownX;
private boolean mSwiping;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private int mDownPosition;
private View mDownView;
private boolean mPaused;

/**
 * The callback interface used by {@link SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener} to inform its client
 * about a successful dismissal of one or more list item positions.
 */
public interface DismissCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called to determine whether the given position can be dismissed.
     */
    boolean canDismiss(int position);

    /**
     * Called when the user has indicated they she would like to dismiss one or more list item
     * positions.
     *
     * @param listView               The originating {@link ListView}.
     * @param reverseSortedPositions An array of positions to dismiss, sorted in descending
     *                               order for convenience.
     */
    void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new swipe-to-dismiss touch listener for the given list view.
 *
 * @param listView  The list view whose items should be dismissable.
 * @param callbacks The callback to trigger when the user has indicated that she would like to
 *                  dismiss one or more list items.
 */
public SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(ListView listView, DismissCallbacks callbacks) {
    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity() * 16;
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    mListView = listView;
    mCallbacks = callbacks;
}

/**
 * Enables or disables (pauses or resumes) watching for swipe-to-dismiss gestures.
 *
 * @param enabled Whether or not to watch for gestures.
 */
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mPaused = !enabled;
}

/**
 * Returns an {@link android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener} to be added to the {@link
 * ListView} using {@link ListView#setOnScrollListener(android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener)}.
 * If a scroll listener is already assigned, the caller should still pass scroll changes through
 * to this listener. This will ensure that this {@link SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener} is
 * paused during list view scrolling.</p>
 *
 * @see SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener
 */
public AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
    return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
    };
}

/**
 * Manually cause the item at the given position to be dismissed (trigger the dismiss
 * animation).
 */
public void dismiss(int position) {
    dismiss(getViewForPosition(position), position, true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (mPaused) {
                return false;
            }

            // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

            // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
            int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
            mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
            View child;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                child.getHitRect(rect);
                if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                    mDownView = child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (mDownView != null) {
                mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);
                if (mCallbacks.canDismiss(mDownPosition)) {
                    mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                    mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
                } else {
                    mDownView = null;
                }
            }
            view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            float velocityX = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity();
            float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
            float absVelocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean dismiss = false;
            boolean dismissRight = false;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2) {
                dismiss = true;
                dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= absVelocityX && absVelocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                    && absVelocityY < absVelocityX) {
                // dismiss only if flinging in the same direction as dragging
                dismiss = (velocityX < 0) == (deltaX < 0);
                dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
            }
            if (dismiss) {
                // dismiss
                dismiss(mDownView, mDownPosition, dismissRight);
            } else {
                // cancel
                mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
            }
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownView = null;
            mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            if (mDownView != null) {
                // cancel
                mDownView.animate()
                        .translationX(0)
                        .alpha(1)
                        .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                        .setListener(null);
            }
            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownView = null;
            mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
            mSwiping = false;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                mSwiping = true;
                mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
                        (motionEvent.getActionIndex()
                                << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                cancelEvent.recycle();
            }

            if (mSwiping) {
                mDownView.setTranslationX(deltaX);
                mDownView.setAlpha(Math.max(0.15f, Math.min(1f,
                        1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void dismiss(final View view, final int position, boolean dismissRight) {
    ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
    if (view == null) {
        // No view, shortcut to calling onDismiss to let it deal with adapter
        // updates and all that.
        mCallbacks.onDismiss(mListView, new int[] { position });
        return;
    }

    view.animate()
            .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
            .alpha(0)
            .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    performDismiss(view, position);
                }
            });
}

private View getViewForPosition(int position) {
    int index = position
            - (mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - mListView.getHeaderViewsCount());
    return (index >= 0 && index < mListView.getChildCount())
            ? mListView.getChildAt(index)
            : null;
}

class PendingDismissData implements Comparable<PendingDismissData> {
    public int position;
    public View view;

    public PendingDismissData(int position, View view) {
        this.position = position;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PendingDismissData other) {
        // Sort by descending position
        return other.position - position;
    }
}

private void performDismiss(final View dismissView, final int dismissPosition) {
    // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
    // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
    // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
    final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
            if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.
                // Sort by descending position
                Collections.sort(mPendingDismisses);

                int[] dismissPositions = new int[mPendingDismisses.size()];
                for (int i = mPendingDismisses.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    dismissPositions[i] = mPendingDismisses.get(i).position;
                }
                mCallbacks.onDismiss(mListView, dismissPositions);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                for (PendingDismissData pendingDismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                    // Reset view presentation
                    pendingDismiss.view.setAlpha(1f);
                    pendingDismiss.view.setTranslationX(0);
                    lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = originalHeight;
                    pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }

                mPendingDismisses.clear();
            }
        }
    });

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    mPendingDismisses.add(new PendingDismissData(dismissPosition, dismissView));
    animator.start();
}
 }
```

**DatabaseHandler**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scheduleManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_EVENTS = "events";


// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EVENTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */


//adding an event (NEEDS TO ADD DRAWABLE)
 public void addEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, event.get_Id()); //Event ID
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title()); // Event Title
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time()); // Event Time
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date()); // Event Date
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE, event.get_image()); // Event RESOURCEID

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_EVENTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

   // Getting single contact
   public Event getEvent(int id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

       Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_EVENTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
               KEY_TITLE, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE, KEY_IMAGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
               new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
       if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

       Event event = new Event(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
               cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getBlob(4));
       // return contact
       return event;
   }


    // Getting All Contacts
   public ArrayList<Event> getAllContacts() {
      ArrayList<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
      // Select All Query
      String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;

      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      // looping through all rows and adding to list
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          do {

              Event event = new Event();
              event.set_Id(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
              event.set_title(cursor.getString(1));
              event.set_time(cursor.getString(2));
              event.set_date(cursor.getString(3));                          
              event.set_image(cursor.getBlob(4));
              eventList.add(event);
          } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }

      // return contact list
      return eventList;
  }

// Getting event Count
    public int getEventsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_EVENTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

 // Updating single contact
    public int updateEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, event.get_title());
        values.put(KEY_TIME, event.get_time());
        values.put(KEY_DATE, event.get_date());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_EVENTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteEvent(Event event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_EVENTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(event.get_Id()) });
        db.close();
    }

}
```

**EventAdapter**

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    //adding drawable to imageview
    ImageView img;
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
    TextView date;
}

public EventAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Event> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.date_detail);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Event event = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_detail, null);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);

        //adding drawable to imageview
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(event._title);
    viewHolder.time.setText(event._time);
    viewHolder.date.setText(event._date);

    //convert from byte array to bitmap               
    Bitmap bitmap = convertByteArrayToBitmap(event._image);
    // CONVERT BITMAP TO DRAWABLE
    viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(
        byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

}

Comment: "I am not really sure what the problem is" -> please include the complete stacktrace for the exception. The place in your code where the exception occurs is listed there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView does not refresh dynamically and causes Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985574/listview-does-not-refresh-dynamically-and-causes-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the following lines of code in the swipeDismissViewListener and the OnActivityResult.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
 EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(context, db.getAllContacts());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to remove the first item from an empty list. It says so in the exception text.

Comment: Okay. Well, I am confused as to why it is "empty" as I can see the list presented to me. I am populating the ArrayList from the SQLite DB. Do you mind elaborating a little bit?

Comment: I checked to see if the ArrayList was Empty and its Size and it doesn't correlate with what you are saying. Any other ideas?

Comment: Use the Eclipse debugger and put a breakpoint just before the point of the exception. It is amazing how much one can learn by examining all the variables and seeing what looks incorrect. You may have to stop at the debug point several times but that will give you a good look at the coded behavior.

Comment: @ItzHoudini - it's not me saying it, it's the exception's text. I seriously doubt you've found a bug in the Java library or the JVM. You're probably looking at the wrong ArrayList. Do as Gravitoid recommended and use a debugger.