# ListView does not refresh dynamically and causes Error

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am unable to remove an object in a ListView. I have been trying to remove an object from an adapter, and then call onDataSetChanged(); but it does not seem to ever remove the object from the screen.

I can successfully remove the object from the database, but the object persists on screen regardless.

I believe that because the view does not refresh properly, it allows me to continue to swipe-to-dismiss the items in the list and eventually leads to an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

**Does anyone see why my ListView will not update properly?** I know there are plenty of questions similar to this one, but most refer to onDataSetChanged() as a solution, and it doesn't seem to be my problem.

```
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011): Process: com.example.datetracker, PID: 9011
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:           Invalid index 0, size is 0
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at   java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at com.example.datetracker.MainActivity$1.onDismiss(MainActivity.java:97)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at com.example.datetracker.SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener$3.onAnimationEnd(SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.java:362)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1056)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:50)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:644)
06-01 19:33:46.734: E/AndroidRuntime(9011):     at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:660)
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
List<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

Context context;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // ///////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, db.getAllContacts());

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    context = this;

    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
            listView,
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {

                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(context,
                        db.getAllContacts());

                @Override
                public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(ListView listView,
                        int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

                        adapter.addAll(db.getAllContacts());
                        db.deleteEvent(adapter.getItem(position));
                        adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                    }
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    // Setting this scroll listener is required to ensure that during

    // // ListView scrolling,
    // // we don't look for swipes.
    listView.setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());

    adapter.addAll(db.getAllContacts());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// @Override
// protected void onResume() {
// // TODO Auto-generated method stub
// super.onResume();
// //
// /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
// DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
// //
// /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// super.onResume();
// adapter.swapItems(db.getAllContacts());
// }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, db.getAllContacts());

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            Bitmap bitmap = b.getParcelable("BITMAP");

            // ///CONVERTING A BITMAP TO A BYTE[]
            byte[] image = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            image = bos.toByteArray();
            // ///////

            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
            /**
             * CRUD OPERATIONS
             */

            Log.e("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addEvent(new Event((int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 101),
                    title, time, date, image));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");

            adapter.addAll(db.getAllContacts());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // logging all events

            for (Event ev : db.getAllContacts()) {
                String log = "Id: " + ev.get_Id() + " ,Title: "
                        + ev.get_title() + " ,Date: " + ev.get_date()
                        + " ,RESOURCEID: " + ev.get_image();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Name: ", log);

            }

            // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

    }
}
}
```

**EventAdapter**

```
public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event> {

private List<Event> events;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    //adding drawable to imageview
    ImageView img;
    TextView title;
    TextView time;
    TextView date;
}

public EventAdapter(Context context, List<Event> objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.date_detail);
    this.events = events;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Event event = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_detail, null);
        viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
        viewHolder.date = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);

        //adding drawable to imageview
        viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    viewHolder.title.setText(event._title);
    viewHolder.time.setText(event._time);
    viewHolder.date.setText(event._date);

    //convert from byte array to bitmap               
    Bitmap bitmap = convertByteArrayToBitmap(event._image);
    // CONVERT BITMAP TO DRAWABLE
    viewHolder.img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

public static Bitmap convertByteArrayToBitmap(
        byte[] byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap, 0,
            byteArrayToBeCOnvertedIntoBitMap.length);
        return bitmap;
    }

public void swapItems(List<Event> events) {
    this.events = events;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure where the problem is but I suggest for you to first Uninstall the application first then run it once again to make sure that the database entries are updated. Second is to make sure to remove the entry on the list first then use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before deleting the entry on your database.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean by removing the object from the list. I am strictly using the EventAdapter which utilizes List<Event> but I am not sure how to reference that list directly? I seem to be crashing when the "adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));" is executed regardless of where it is in the code.

Comment: I think you should use listView.remove(listView.getItem(position)) then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() instead? Also I guess you need to review your code on SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener. Not sure why you add all items from your database, delete, remove then clear the adapter on this part.

Comment: I am just going to keep messing around with it. I have tried so many different ways to populate the adapter, whether it be directly from the database like it is now or from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the following lines of code in the swipeDismissViewListener and the OnActivityResult.

`DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
 EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(context, db.getAllContacts());`